# How to Send an SMS to Myself

Tags: java, android, sms

How can I send an SMS to myself on Android? I want to enter a sender and fictitious content, and have it appear in the SMS notifications bar.

Answer (score 3):

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("DESTINATION NUMBER", null, "Your Message Text", null, null);
```

Also in your Android Manifest file, add the following permission:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
```

Or if you would like to send a SMS with more than 160 characters:

```
String phoneNo = "INSERT NR HERE";
String message = "This is a long message that is supposed to be longer than 160 characters.";

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList msgparts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);

smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msgparts, null, null);
```

Comment: is not how I want. I phoneNo = my device ?. message to myself ?

Comment: Samples                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789"); 
values.put("body", "foo bar"); 
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values); 
 
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms://"));
startActivity(sendIntent);          just do not wanna read the message immediately want to stay in the notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send message to yourself, then you can use [notification Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).
Call below function when you want get notification. Pass message string and title string for this notification.  [Here is good tutorial for you](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

You also need [Pending Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)  to send this notification after specific task completed or while. `Pending Intent` allows the foreign application to use your application's permissions to execute a predefined piece of code.
Here is code which might be help you.

```
protected void sendnotification (String title, String message) {
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);       
int icon = R.drawable.icon;
CharSequence tickerText = message;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = title;
CharSequence contentText = message;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Comment: means you need to send this notification in inbox?

Comment: you can't store notification in Inbox. Notification are use to only notify. you can use notification manager notify yourself for second or use SMS Manager and store this sms into inbox.

Comment: how to SMS Manager and store this sms into inbox? helpe.

Comment: Thank you to all the answers, could.

Answer (score -1):

If SMS is not mandatory, you can also send chat messages to yourself.

Two projects achieving this :

- Nimrod, for Facebook Messenger : https://www.nimrod-messenger.io/
- Telegram Middleman, for Telegram : https://github.com/n1try/telegram-middleman-bot